# My Angular Select2 dropdown needs to pass more values than just options' names on change event

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, jquery-select2, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I'm using Angular-Select2 and what I need is actually on change collect some more values than just what currently chosen options have as their names.
For example, if options `Red`, `Blue`, `Yellow` are selected, the current value is array of those values. What I want to do is to have displayed below the select box all those (in this example) colors that are chosen. It works so far - "colors" are showing and as I remove one from the select box (as tags, by clicking X sign) the bottom updates accordingly.

What I need to further accomplish is to send along other values, or at least one (id) so I can query my database. I know, I could include it before the actual name and then remove in my list to be able to manipulate it separately but then the id is also shown in the dropdown list and within selected options.

How to proceed? Is there anything that may be attached to options and sent and readable within the below area in which textual selected options' text is shown.

I'm wathching for changes like this:

```
$scope.$watch('selectDiseaseState', function(newVal){
    $scope.listDiagnosis = newVal;
});
```

EDIT: If confused - this is multiselect dropdown.
EDIT:

The select2 markup:

```
<select id="mySel2" ng-model="selectDiseaseState" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Start typing a name of disease state...">
    <optgroup ng-repeat="item in select" label="{{item.label}}">
        <option ng-repeat="option in item.options">{{option.value}}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your `ng-model` in the `ng-options` binding using array of objects instead of simple array. You can then watch for changes on the dropdown and the newvalue will be the object containing all properties.
**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='controller'>
    <select ng-model='selectDiseaseState' ng-options='item as item.Color for item in selectOptions'> 
    </select>
</div>
```

**Angular code**:
var app= angular.module('app', [])
.controller('controller', function($scope){

```
$scope.selectOptions = [
    {Id: 1, Color: 'Red'},
    {Id: 2, Color: 'Blue'},
    {Id: 3, Color: 'Green'},
    {Id: 4, Color: 'Yellow'}
];
$scope.selectDiseaseState = {};

$scope.$watch('selectDiseaseState', function(newVal){
    $scope.listDiagnosis = newVal;
    alert('Id: '+ $scope.listDiagnosis.Id + ' and Color: '+ $scope.listDiagnosis.Color);
});
```

});

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9m77zrzo/2/)**

Comment: Actually I didnt mention I was using optgroups (for categories, which in turn use a separate ng-repeat loops) in which then  there is a nested loop for options
Another thing, people say ng-options doesn't play nicely with Select2 + Angular so I'm using these nested ng-repeat loops to create my optgroups with appropriate options.